# How Can Knex (or Any NPM Package) Run a Different Version of Node?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to use Knex's `seed:run` command (ie. `npx knex seed:run`), and inside my seed file I've added this line, which logs the version of Node that it's being run with:

```
console.log(process.version);
```

Now, if I run that *exact* same line of code in the Node command prompt itself (`node`), I get:

> v14.2.0

Similarly, when I run `node --version` it correctly returns `v14.2.0`.

However, when Knex runs my seed file, I instead see:

> v11.15.0

Can anyone explain how/why Knex is using a different version of Node, and how I can make it stop?

P.S. I've tried wiping my `node_modules` folder out and re-installing via `npm i`, but Knex continues to use an old Node somehow.  Knex itself is installed at the latest version (`0.21.1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Danizavtz's answer didn't solve thigns for me, but it did point me in the right direction.  I realized that I *did* have two versions of Node: one installed by Linux (using `apt-get`), and one I'd installed myself (to get a newer version of Node).

The solution for me was to remove the system version of Node with:

```
sudo apt-get remove node
```

That left me with a working Node ... but it removed my `npm`.  I guess I could have just re-installed everything, but since I already had `node` and just needed `npm`, I downloaded the latest Node installation and used the `node` in it to install `npm`.  I did this both with and without `sudo` (I'm not sure if doing it without `sudo` was even necessary, as it didn't fix things):

```
sudo ~/node-v14.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node ~/node-v14.3.0-linux-x64/bin/npm i -g npm
```

After that I finally got the expected Node version when I ran `npx`/`npm`!

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you have a global installation that runs in privileged account (root), and a local installation to current user. 
It is possible you are using some node versioning tool to manage nodejs versions, it creates a symbolic link to a managed version of node that overrides the default configuration. There are many tools that does that like nvm, n.

Comment: That is helpful, but could you explain how I might remedy this?  I am not using `n/`nvm`, but am on Linux, so I guess it's possible the super user account *might* have a different version of Node ... but even if it did, I don't understand how I can run `npx` (as a normal user) and `knex` can somehow magically run as the super user (or any other user): that should not be possible on any UNIX system?  Also when I `which node` it tells me `/usr/bin/node`, and that path isn't a symbolic link or anything ... and even if it was, I'm still unclear on how `npx` runs a different version than `node`.

Comment: when you run with npm (not npx), what happen with version number?

Comment: Same as npx: `v11.15.0`. BTW I am adding the `--esm` flag to `knex` (since I'm using ES Modules), and I'm providing a `NODE_PATH` environmental variable, but I doubt either detail is relevant.

Comment: this is the result from my execution: npx -v --> `/usr/local/bin/npx`  which node --> `/usr/local/bin/node`